# How to display design images that are not published as part of a Component

Tags: dxa

I have uploaded images that are part of the design like sprites and background image within HTML-Design zip file in the following path `html-design\src\system\assets\images\sprite-tabs.svg` (for example). 
When the design is published the folder structure is so `\BinaryData\3\system\assets\images`. I call this image from within the CSS and from the page.

```
.tabs-main a{border:0;background:url(/system/assets/images/sprite-tabs.svg) no-repeat 0 0;}
```

and

```
<img src="/system/v0.08/assets/images/circle.png" width="274" height="99">
```

Both times the image doesn't appear. Is there something wrong in my setup.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to log it as an enhancement request on https://github.com/sdl/dxa-html-design/issues/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your setup, only that currently the HTML design is built with the rules to discard any images that come out of it. So only the JavaScript and CSS files will be published to the broker, hence your images are not available.

If you want to change this behavior, you will need to modify the `Gruntfile.js` from the `build-files.zip`, and after that republish the HMTL design.

The part where the images are discarded is the following:

```
copy: {
    dist: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= config.src %>',
            dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
            src: [
                // ignore all images (unless we really need some)
                //'system/assets/images/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
                //'system/assets/less/**/*',
                //'system/assets/scripts/theme-customiser.js',
                'system/assets/scripts/PIE.htc',
                'system/assets/fonts/*'
            ]
        },
```

The reason why the images were discarded, is because it didn't make sense to publish all examples images from the whitelabel HTML design (since they are simply example content). But unfortunately that also means we currently don't have support for design images, something I have open on the backlog and will try to add in a future release.

Mind you the sprites story I follow, but background images, I would argue if they should actually be content or part of the HTML design. I guess it depends on what type of background image you are talking about exactly.

Comment: Thanks Bart. I modified the commented portion and republished the HTML designs. I can see my images now.